# C++ HTTP socket recv does not show image request from the browser

Tags: c++, http, sockets, webserver

I am trying to implement a simple web server in C++ and so far, I have successfully sent `text/html` data including hyperlinks. However, in my HTML file, I added an `img` tag.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Simple Web Server</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, Web Server!</h1>
        <img src="cat.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not yet interested in sending the image over the network. I am trying to decode the request. On my browser, the *Network bar* from Developer tools says that `index.html` has `200 OK` but it does not send any request about the image (I can see the image on the *Network bar*). The page also keeps loading endlessly, while previewing the received html file without the image.

Printing the requested file from `recv`, I get the following repeatedly:

```
Request file: /
```

It seems that I do not get any request about the image? Specifically, I'm trying to find `GET /cat.jpg HTTP/1.1` but there doesn't seem to be any.

Below are *minimal* reproducible example of my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

std::vector<std::string> 
parse_request(char request_string[], ssize_t r_len)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::istringstream r_stream (request_string);
    std::string tok;
    int counter = 0;
    while (r_stream >> tok && counter++ < 3)
        tokens.push_back(tok);

    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    int socket_fd { socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) }, newclientfd;
    bzero((char*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(8000);    

    if (bind(socket_fd, (sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0)
        perror("ERROR: bind");
    
    socklen_t clientlen {(socklen_t) sizeof(sockaddr_in)};

    if (listen(socket_fd, 5) < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR: listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        char recv_buffer[1024];
        newclientfd = accept(socket_fd, (sockaddr*) &client_addr, &clientlen);
        ssize_t recv_size { recv(newclientfd, recv_buffer, 1024, 0) };
        std::vector<std::string> request { parse_request(recv_buffer, strlen(recv_buffer)) };
        std::string fname { request[1] };

        std::cout << "Request file: " << fname << std::endl;

        /* For creating full file path. */
        std::ostringstream string_builder;
        
        /* Build our full path to the html file. */
        string_builder << ".";

        if (request[1] == "/")
            string_builder << "/index.html";
        else 
            string_builder << request[1];
        
        /* Open the file */
        std::ifstream html_file(string_builder.str());
        html_file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        int file_size = html_file.tellg();
        std::string file_buffer(file_size, ' ');
        html_file.seekg(0);
        html_file.read(&file_buffer[0], file_size);
        const char* buf = file_buffer.c_str();

        char page_buffer[4096];
        sprintf(page_buffer, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\n\r\n%s", file_size, buf);
        printf("%s", page_buffer);

        /* Send it to the client. */
        if (send(newclientfd, (void*) page_buffer, strlen(page_buffer), 0) == -1)
            fprintf(stderr, "Sending to client failed! Error code %d\n", errno);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why is not receiving any request regarding `cat.jpg`? What's the proper way to handle multiple files in one HTML page, such as images?

Comment: What you show so far does not look too bad. This means the problem is likely not in the code you show. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich! I edited it and gave the least code I could create that shows my problem. Thanks!

Comment: What I see as potential problems: 1. you expect that `send` will send everything, which is not guaranteed though - you need to check how much is actually send.  2. You implicitly declare HTTP keep-alive by using HTTP/1.1, you don't close the socket after sending, yet you don't read from the original socket anymore but instead the client to create a new connection. The client might send the new request over the existing connection though, even if you don't read from it.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich. The main cause was your second point. I forgot to close the new fd.